# when to and when not to use "this" in JSX event handler function reference?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, this

I'm trying to do [this ReactJS Tagging tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-gzXKEziik).

I'm about half-way through, and my code is [on Codepen here](https://codepen.io/xmatic/pen/QzwZLy?editors=0011). (I am leaving this Pen as is, and won't be making further changes to it.)

As you can see, at one point in the code, my event handler in JSX looks like this:

```
onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp}
```

and at another point, it looks like this:

```
onClick={onDeleteTag}
```

My question is: why was `this.` necessary in the first case but not the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is necessary if you're trying to reference a function/value that is outside of the scope of the current function (`render()` in your case) but is still encapsulated in an object or class.

```
const foo = () => 'foo';

class Clazz {

    otherFunc() {
        return 'otherFunc';
    }

    render() {
        const bar = () => 'bar';

        bar() // can call directly

        this.otherFunc() // necessary as it's a "sibling" function

        foo(); // not necessary as it's a global function in this module's scope
    }
}
```